# Cannot set the command text for dataset error in SSRS 2008 R2 while getting data from MYSQL

Tags: mysql, reporting-services

I have searched through all the posts I could find regarding the "Cannot set the command text for dataset" error I am getting, and everything that users suggest, still results in this error for me.

I am working in SSRS 2008R2, and I am connecting via ODBC to a MYSQL connection.

```
="SELECT case when tranHour between '00' and '03' 
         then DATE_format(DATE_SUB(trandate,INTERVAL 1 DAY), '%Y-%m-%d')
         else DATE_format(trandate, '%Y-%m-%d') 
         end as WorkDay, 
         case when tranHour between '03' and '15' then 'AM' 
         else 'PM' 
         end as Shift, 
         'Station1' AS Station, 
         count(*) as 'Scans', 
         ROUND(SUM(elapsed_seconds)/60/60,2) as 'Hours',
         ROUND(count(*)/(SUM(elapsed_seconds)/60/60),2) as 'Scans/Hour',
         season 
FROM data_lite.master_lite_134_301 
where SEASON IN ('" + join(Parameters!ReportParameter1.Value,"','") + "')
group by WorkDay, Shift 
ORDER BY DATE_format(WorkDay, '%Y-%m-%d') DESC"
```

Every time I get this error...

An error occurred during local report processing.
Cannot set the command text for dataset 'AMPM'
Error during processing of the CommandText expression of dataset 'AMPM'

If I replace the Parameter with an actual value, it runs fine.

So with **where SEASON = '15F'** , it runs, 
with **where SEASON IN ('" + join(Parameters!ReportParameter1.Value,"','") + "')** , it gets this error

Comment: Thank you for the formatting correction genespos. Same error still occurring though.

Comment: Does your SQL works if it is hardcoded as `SEASON IN ('15F', '15S')`

Comment: Old post, so I won't bother with an answer, but the issue is the + concatenation operator. Remember that SSRS code is largely VB, and in VB the string concatenation operator is &, not +... :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue. I had everything correct my tables, fields and query as well. What resolved my issue was checking "multiple values" box in parameters.

Go to your parameters --> double click on it --> If you have default value set it in default value tab --> In general tab check multiple values option.
Build your report again/ delete the .rdl.data file from the folder and then check your report it should work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

change your *CASE* to

```
SELECT  case when ( tranHour between '03' and '15') then 'AM' 
         else 'PM' 
         end CASE as Shift;
```

**so**

```
="SELECT case when tranHour between '00' and '03' 
         then DATE_format(DATE_SUB(trandate,INTERVAL 1 DAY), '%Y-%m-%d')
         else DATE_format(trandate, '%Y-%m-%d') 
         end as WorkDay, 
         case when ( tranHour between '03' and '15') then 'AM' 
         else 'PM' 
         end CASE as Shift, 
         'Station1' AS Station, 
         count(*) as 'Scans', 
         ROUND(SUM(elapsed_seconds)/60/60,2) as 'Hours',
         ROUND(count(*)/(SUM(elapsed_seconds)/60/60),2) as 'Scans/Hour',
         season 
FROM data_lite.master_lite_134_301 
where SEASON IN ('" + join(Parameters!ReportParameter1.Value,"','") + "')
group by WorkDay, Shift 
ORDER BY DATE_format(WorkDay, '%Y-%m-%d') DESC"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to map the Query parameter with the corresponding Report parameter.

In `Dataset properties` go to `Parameters` tab, map the name of the query parameter with name of the report parameter.

[image]

Now in your query you can use the parameter in this way - only if it is a multivalue parameter.

```
SELECT case when tranHour between '00' and '03' 
         then DATE_format(DATE_SUB(trandate,INTERVAL 1 DAY), '%Y-%m-%d')
         else DATE_format(trandate, '%Y-%m-%d') 
         end as WorkDay, 
         case when tranHour between '03' and '15' then 'AM' 
         else 'PM' 
         end as Shift, 
         'Station1' AS Station, 
         count(*) as 'Scans', 
         ROUND(SUM(elapsed_seconds)/60/60,2) as 'Hours',
         ROUND(count(*)/(SUM(elapsed_seconds)/60/60),2) as 'Scans/Hour',
         season 
FROM data_lite.master_lite_134_301 
where SEASON IN (@QueryYearParameter)
group by WorkDay, Shift 
ORDER BY DATE_format(WorkDay, '%Y-%m-%d') DESC
```

> Note `Parameter Name` property and the parameter I use in the query is
>   the same.

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Thanks but no, that didn't resolve it either. I did figure it out already though. Thank you

Comment: @DanA, what was your solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

SSRS is funny about its spaces at the end of lines in the expressions.  I had the same issue and SSRS was combining the last word of the line with the first word of the next line.  Just add a space in at the end of every line.

OR

Wrap your JOIN func in CSTR().  so... CSTR(join(Parameters!ReportParameter1.Value,"','"))